# How can I debug or set a break statement inside a compiled expression tree?

Tags: c#, linq, debugging, expression-trees

When an external library contains a LINQ provider, and it throws an exception when executing a dynamic expression tree, how can I break when that expression is thrown?

For example, I use a third party LINQ2CRM provider, which allows me to call the `Max<TSource, TResult>()` method of `IQueryable`, but when it throws an `InvalidCastException`, I fail to break on the spot when the exception is thrown, making it hard to review the stack-trace because it's already unwinded when the debugger breaks it in my code. I've set "break on throw" for the mentioned exception. My debug settings are:

[image]

---

Clarification on where exactly I'd want to break. I *do not* want to break in side the LINQ Expression, but instead, I want to break when the expression tree is executed, or, put in other words, when the `IQueryable` extension method `Max()` calls the override provided by the LINQ provider. The top of the stacktrace looks like this, which is where I would like to break inside (or step through, or whatever):

```
at XrmLinq.QueryProviderBase.Execute[T](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Max[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
```

Comment: Do you mean stick a breakpoint in part of a lambda expression in one of those methods?

Comment: Not sure if [this helps](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/), but I'm doing a search now as this is interesting. All roads appear to go to LinqPad. I can't see how you'd be able to breakpoint it without the source code though, and then when you have the source, can't you just breakpoint in the part of the provider responsible for `Max`?

Comment: The [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) MSDN section also has a section for [Debugging Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee725345). I think this is where I have to stop searching and get back to work ;-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I'm still reading up on your finds. Neither of the links seem to actually allow me to break in an expression tree, but it does give me some pointers to how I could force it to. Still trying though...

Comment: Do you have the source to `XrmLinq.QueryProviderBase`?  F11 should just step on in there, right?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you expect to see in the debugger? Since the debugger knows nothing about run-time generated code you can only see the JITed code. Press CTRL-ALT-E, mark: break when CLR exceptions are thrown

Comment: @adrianm: What I expect is either source code (as in before the expression is JITted, after all, it uses reflection), or assembly, but I see neither. I've already checked the CLR exception (as I said in my question), and it breaks, but not at the actual place where the exception is thrown.

Comment: A compiled expression does not have any source code. It might be created from source but that information is not included in the expression. Have you really looked at the debugger call stack when it breaks (not the exception call stack)?

Comment: @adrianm: when it breaks, the call stack is empty (well, only the normal call chain of the containing method is visible). The call stack in the exception contains slightly more information (see question body). Also, the compiled expression is compiled into IL and only then JITted, so the IL should be available.

Comment: @jonnyGold: no, I don't have the source. But most of the time, that isn't an issue, either Reflector, Resharper or VS itself provides a reverse engineered version of the IL. But not now and F11 doesn't jump inside, it skips over.

Comment: Try Windbg instead. It will give you access to much more information.

Comment: What do you see if you go into the menus `Debug / Exceptions` and turn on **thrown as well as uncaught** for the exception that is occurring?  It may only take you to your code, but the 'X' of your Linq _may_ be set to what you want.

Comment: What is the value of InnerException property?

Comment: @JesseChisholm: I don't have that option. I remember I _had_ it though, was it removed with VS2010? I only have a column for "thrown".

Comment: @Abel - they didn't so much **get rid of it** as the more typical Microsoft game of **renaming and moving it**.  You should still have `Debug / Exceptions` as a menu option.  The **as well as uncaught** is now assumed and the checkbox column is merely labeled **Thrown**.  You should dig down in the tree to the specific Exception you are interested in, as MS uses exceptions internally to manage code flow.  You do NOT want to break at all those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may not be understanding the problem, but instead of actually breaking on the line (which doesn't appear to be possible), would it be enough to put a try-catch inside your expression tree and log the exception?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var logExceptionMethod = typeof (Program).GetMethod("LogException", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var createFileMethod = typeof (System.IO.File).GetMethod("Create", new[] {typeof(string)});

    // Parameter for the catch block
    var exception = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Exception));

    var expression =
        Expression.TryCatch(
        Expression.Block(typeof(void),
            // Try to create an invalid file
            Expression.Call(createFileMethod, Expression.Constant("abcd/\\"))),

            // Log the exception from the catch                  
            Expression.Catch(exception, Expression.Call(logExceptionMethod, exception)));

    Expression.Lambda<Action>(expression).Compile()();
}

static void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Console output:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
at lambda_method(Closure )
```